# simulating a car on google maps that randomly decides where to turn (without destination)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would be very happy if someone could help me on this. i am planing to write a script that simulates a moving car on google maps. simply a marker that is traveling across the roads. the point is that it has to move and turn randomly on the roads, i mean without a end destination. it should just need a starting point and decide on its own where it has to turn.

here for example it moves across the destination: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip.htm

what i need is to give it just one location and it starts to move and turn randomly and continuously.

is that possible. and how can i accomplish that. i would really appreciate if i could get a lead.

PS: at the same time i need to store each moves coordinated in to the database.

Comment: 2 things: 1) the example you mentioned uses the v2 of the API which is deprecated. 2) the car must follow a path. So if something has to be random, it would be the path.

Comment: yes you are right v2 is deprecated, i have to use v3 which makes it difficult. what do you mean by the path has to be random. do you mean like, the marker has to decide which next path it has to switch after it reaches the end of the current path?

Comment: No. Your car must follow a path. It will not follow streets randomly. So if you want to randomize the car journey, you need to find a way to create random paths.

Comment: you mean i have first to crete random path an then move the marker on it? i guess that way would make it impossible to be continuously :(

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. You could create paths that start and end at the same point though...

Comment: i will consider this solution. thank you @MrUpsidown for your recommendation.

Comment: @Skeletor I am having the same requirement in iOS. If you get a solution, could you please post the logic how to achieve this?